# Inserting string with unknown encodings in Postgres DB

Tags: python, postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding

A Python (python3) script I created parses a JSON object and stores the values associated with the keys in a Postgres database. I have been struggling with inserting strings containing unknown codecs. Since the JSON datasets are derived from numerous sources, the codec/encoding cannot be known in advance.

```
test@ubuntu:~$ python3 psql.py json-to-parse.json
Error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 24: ordinal not in range(256)
Error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 16: ordinal not in range(256)
Error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 1457-1458: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I have tried to replace non-UTF8 Characters from the string using regex but it doesn't seem like an optimal solution. However, I have gone through StackOverflow but could not find a reliable solution for the same issue.

Previously I had encountered the same issue but moved to MySQL because I couldn't find any workarounds but it doesn't seem as fast as PostgreSQL when working on huge datasets.

A sample JSON Object that on inserting its values into Postgres Database results in the following error:

```
'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 1: ordinal not in range(256)
```

test.json:

````
{"timestamp":"2022-08-27T12:23:46.71654409Z","title":"1\ufffd-\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd: \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd","scheme":"https","webserver":"nginx","response-body":"aaa"}```
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your ubuntu not postgres are you running this in a container? or local machine make sure whatever u are running it on supports those characters. if you are ussing docker images dont use stripped versions